# Apex Toolkit How to Create Embedded Signing Session for Contact that Isn't Logged in

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign Apex Toolkit. We have a scenario where a sales representative is logged into Salesforce and is working with an in-person contact to fill out an application. Once they fill out the required fields in the application we would like to create an embedded signing session for the contact to sign a document.

I am following the instructions for Embedded Signing using the toolkit.  I see that we have to create an embedded signer using the following method dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner(). We have found that when we start the signing session the first recipient is always the user that is logged in. Instead, we need the recipient to be the contact related to the application. Is there any way to start an embedded signing session for the contact?

Answer (score 0):

See code example below. You can replace the `myContact.Email` and `myContact.Name` with whatever you need to achieve your objective.

```
public class ApexToolkitDemo {
public static void sendEnvelopeMethod() {
Id mySourceId; // The ID of the initiating Salesforce object.
// Create an empty envelope.
dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));
// The initiating Salesforce entity.
// Use myEnvelope for later
// Use a Salesforce contact record as a Recipient here
Contact myContact = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
// Use the Recipient.fromSource method to create the Recipient
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
myContact.Name, // Recipient name
myContact.Email, // Recipient email
null, // Optional phone number
'Signer 1', // Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
new dfsle.Entity(myContact.Id)); // Source object for the Recipient
// Add Recipient to the Envelope
myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { myRecipient });
```